# Error message when installing Chinese input

Tags: package-management, chinese

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and I was trying to install the Chinese input. I got the following error message:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
Details:
cmap-adobe-cns1 cmap-adobe-gb1 fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming  
 ibus-sunpinyin ibus-table-cangjie ibus-table-cangjie-big ibus-table-cangjie3  
 ibus-table-cangjie5 ibus-table-wubi libchewing3 libchewing3-data libsunpinyin3  
 python-glade2 sunpinyin-data ttf-arphic-ukai ttf-wqy-zenhei
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

First I read this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327907&p=8878470#post8878470)  It is not the solution to the problem but it worked very similar. Open

System->Administration->Synaptic Package Manager

Then:

Settings->Repositories

and first looked whether the checkbox "Software restricted by copyright or legal issues" was checked (in my case it was)

After this go to the tab "Other Software" and checked "Canonical Partners" (if you have Source Code installed you may check "Canonical Partners(Source Code)" too) to allow Ubuntu to download from this sources.

Result: All updates should work as before